# Angular 11 wait until subscribe finishes getting data

Tags: async-await, promise, subscription, angular11

I have a auth.service and data.service. auth.service getting data from data.service but it checks before data arrives. So it returns undefined.

auth.service getting data like this;

```
get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  const emailVerify = this.dataservice.userStatService(user.uid);
  console.warn(emailVerify)
  return (user !== null && emailVerify !== false && emailVerify !== undefined ) ? true : false;
}
```

data.service check user status function like this;

```
  userStatService(uid: any): any{
    console.error(uid)
    this.get(uid)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.warn('status set', data.status)
          this.statData =  data.status;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
    });
    return this.statData;
  }
```

and this code works like this now;
[See console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oulhQ.png)

I'm waiting for your code examples, thank you.

Update:
auth.guard code;

```
  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn() !== true) {
      this.router.navigate(['/auth/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: 'dashboard' } })
      .then(() => {
        this.authService.SignOut();
      });
    }else{
    return true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

observables execute asynchronously, you need to return the observable and subscribe in the consumer to use it correctly:

```
 // return observable
 userStatService(uid: any): any{
    console.error(uid)
    return this.get(uid)
 }


isLoggedIn() {
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  this.dataservice.userStatService(user.uid).subscribe(emailVerify => {
    console.warn(emailVerify)
  })
  // really can't do this while working with async execution. doesn't work.
  //return (user !== null && emailVerify !== false && emailVerify !== undefined ) ? true : false;
}
```

if this is for a guard, use the map operator and return the whole observable, angular expects either a boolean or an observable:

```
isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  if (!user)
    return of(false); // null guard and slight performance improvement
  return this.dataservice.userStatService(user.uid).pipe(map(emailVerify => {
    console.warn(emailVerify)
    return (emailVerify !== false && emailVerify !== undefined ) ? true : false;
  }))
}
```

and in your guard you need to again, RETURN THE OBSERVABLE:

```
  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn().pipe(
      map(isLoggedIn => {
        if (!isLoggedIn) {
          this.router.navigate(['/auth/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: 'dashboard' } }).then(() => {
            this.authService.SignOut();
          });
        }
        return isLoggedIn;
      })
    )
  }
```

angular guards will handle the subscribing, but you must return the observable to the guard.

Comment: it works but isLoggedIn must be return a boolean for authguard. How can I check user and emailVerify for authguard?

Comment: angular guards can return observables, updated answer

Comment: console.warn does not log anyting. what could be the problem?

Comment: i can't read code in comments, put your guard code in the question

Comment: okey, i added auth.guard code in the question.

Comment: you're still trying to access an observable like it's synchronous. ya gotta learn the diff between async vs synchronous execution if you're gona do front end dev

Comment: it works! Thank you. But in auth.guard .pipe is showing errors. Thats errors is;

Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'boolean | Observable<boolean>'.
  Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'false'.ts(2339)

Comment: fixed it, slight adjustment for the guard

Comment: Still showing same errors for pipe, i've tried restart ide and re-complie.

Comment: I fixed just remove "Promise<boolean> | boolean " from authService. Works very well.